# Get distinct count of an element using XPath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, distinct-values, xpath-1.0

I have a requirement to get distinct count of some particular element, but I have to only use a single XPath line to fulfil that requirement.

```
<root>
    <Custom1>
        <ZDPANR>PALLET1</ZDPANR>
    </Custom1>
    <Custom1>

        <ZDPANR>PALLET3</ZDPANR>
    </Custom1>
    <Custom1>

        <ZDPANR>PALLET1</ZDPANR>
    </Custom1>
    <Custom1>

        <ZDPANR>PALLET1</ZDPANR>
    </Custom1>
    <Custom1>

        <ZDPANR>PALLET2</ZDPANR>
    </Custom1>
    <Custom1>

        <ZDPANR>PALLET2</ZDPANR>
    </Custom1>
</root>
```

The code that I have tried so far is getting currently the distinct values for `<ZDPANR>` element.

```
<xsl:for-each select="//ZDPANR[not(.=following::ZDPANR) and .!='']">
  <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="count(//ZDPANR[.=(.)])"/><!--Single Xpath line where the count is not coming proper-->
  </td>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I'm able to access current distinct `ZDPANR` using `.` inside `for-each`. But `count(//ZDPANR[.=(.)])` (`.`) is not getting the current `ZDPANR`. If I hardcode `count(//ZDPANR[.='PALLET2'])` like this it's coming correctly. Therefore I want to get current `ZDPANR` in that hardcoded place.
Can somebody help me to achieve this? Because of a tool limitation I can only use Xpath 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a variable inside your loop over the distinct `ZDPANR` elements, and access it in the predicate of your `count()` XPath predicate.

Your input XML,

```
<root>
  <Custom1>
    <ZDPANR>PALLET1</ZDPANR>
  </Custom1>
  <Custom1>
    <ZDPANR>PALLET3</ZDPANR>
  </Custom1>
  <Custom1>
    <ZDPANR>PALLET1</ZDPANR>
  </Custom1>
  <Custom1>
    <ZDPANR>PALLET1</ZDPANR>
  </Custom1>
  <Custom1>
    <ZDPANR>PALLET2</ZDPANR>
  </Custom1>
  <Custom1>
    <ZDPANR>PALLET2</ZDPANR>
  </Custom1>
</root>
```

provided to this updated XSLT,

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <table>
      <xsl:for-each select="//ZDPANR[not(.=following::ZDPANR) and .!='']">
        <xsl:variable name="cur" select="."/>
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="$cur"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="count(//ZDPANR[.=$cur])"/></td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will then yield this output XML,

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>PALLET3</td>
      <td>1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>PALLET1</td>
      <td>3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>PALLET2</td>
      <td>2</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

as requested.